# Unrecognized attribute 'requirePermission' error

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf

I am getting following error:

> Unrecognized attribute 'requirePermission' from machine.config file.

When i trying to login by using WCF services from Windows application which is developed in 1.1.

Please help.

Regards.

Comment: NET 1.1? Use at least .NET 2.0

Comment: @abatischev: That's not always a decision the developer is able to make themself.

Comment: @rmx: There tons of reasons to move from totally obsolete .NET 1.x and there are no real reasons not to do it!

Comment: @rmx maybe not, but in such case he can't use WCF

Comment: Depending on the size of the software, the cost of migrating could be huge - its not up to the dev. It might not even be neccessary to migrate in the first place.

Comment: @rmx: This is expenditure of unavoidable sort

Answer (score 0):

That would indicate that whatever xml schema your config file uses does not include the `requirePermission` element.

What exactly were your steps in producing the error? Maybe go back a step at a time, and find out which step caused it. Or be more specific in your question.

Comment: Actually the problem is because of the Enterprise Library used in application, i have the installer not the code & when i installed & tried with credentials i got the error. In config file following libraries are used.

Comment: <xmlSerializerSection type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
- <enterpriseLibrary.databaseSettings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" defaultInstance="Database Instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/enterpriselibrary/08-31-2004/data">
- <databaseTypes>

Comment: <databaseType name="Sql Server" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" /> 
  </databaseTypes>